# Попробуйте использовать «django.db.backends.XXX», где XXX — одно из:

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Я настраивал Django 4.0 для использования Mongodb, и по какой-то причине он не подключается, и он продолжает выдавать мне эту ошибку:

```
To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX
is one of: 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Вот код из settings.py:

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django',
    'CLIENT': {
            'host': 'mongodb+srv://Vadim:*****@cluster0.mf5xt.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
            'NAME': 'testbase',
            'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1'
        },
```

Как правильно прописать настройку `'ENGINE'`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В графу 'ENGINE' должно быть прописано 'djоngo', а не 'django'.
Так же необходимо было установить данный пакет 'djongo' в проект.

Answer (score 0):

В графу `'ENGINE'` Вы должны прописать не просто `'django'`, а `'django.db.backends.XXX'`, где `XXX` — одна из строк в поле ошибки.

Например, если Вы работаете на MySQL, то Вы должны записать код вот так:

```py
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # ставим mysql вместо SQL
    'CLIENT': {
            'host': 'mongodb+srv://Vadim:*****@cluster0.mf5xt.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
            'NAME': 'testbase',
            'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1'
    },
}
```

Если Вы работаете на Oracle либо PostgreSQL, нужно вместо `mysql` записать `oracle` и `postgresql` соответственно.

Информацию про данное поле и вообще про все настройки можно найти [в документации Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#engine).